# Displaying data In Hour /min/sec

Tags: pic, c

I am using PIC16F886/4 MHz crystal/1 ms timer Interrupt. I have variable named Topdisplay and bottom display. When top display == bottom display the process should stop.
Topdisplay Setvalue
BottomDisplay shows process value.

> Top display set usually in time format if value 0210  means  if
>   LED_SS==0    02Sec 10ms    LED_MS==0    02Min  10S    LED_HM==0    02H
>   10Min

Currently in below code i could able to display setvalue and process value.
**I am looking for C function so that if my Sec paramter reaches 59 s the update value should be 1 min, 59 s should start update again in 0. when it reaches 59S it should update 1m-2M the process continue tell it reaches 2M 10S**
in below code Tpvalue=0210 means bottom display will stop at 0210

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "delay.h"
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

__CONFIG(FOSC_HS & WDTE_ON& PWRTE_ON & CP_OFF & BOREN_ON & LVP_OFF & CPD_OFF  & DEBUG_OFF&MCLRE_ON &BOREN_ON&FCMEN_ON &WRT_OFF);

#define RLY_DRV1     RB4
#define PRG_EN       RA4
#define DISPCLK         RB5
#define DISPDATA        RB6
#define STROBE          RB7
#define RESET           RB1

unsigned char Main_Flag=0;
unsigned char j=0;
unsigned int Bottom_Value=0;
unsigned int Top_Display=1234;

struct {
    unsigned RUNMODE                :1;
    unsigned PRGMODE                :1;
    unsigned KeyLock_RESET1         :1;
    unsigned KeyLock_SELECT1        :1;
    unsigned KeyLock_ADVANCE        :1;

    unsigned BLINKFLAG              :1;
    unsigned BLINKFLAG1             :1;
    unsigned FLASHFLAG              :1;
    unsigned KeyTEST_PRESS          :1;
    unsigned MANUAL_RESET           :1;
    unsigned AUTO_RESET             :1;

} bits;

unsigned char Dec_pt=1;
unsigned char SETPRESS=0;
unsigned char DgtSel=2;
unsigned int Debounce=0;
unsigned char LEDBuffer_1[8];
unsigned int Hour,Min,Sec,Msec;
unsigned char Counter=0;
unsigned char Digit[4] = {0,0,0,0};
const unsigned char DISPTABLE[28] = {0x03,0x9F,0x25,0x0D,0x99,0x49,0x41,0x1F,0x01,0x09,0x11,0x83,0x31,
                                     //0  //1  //2  //3  //4  //5  //6  //7  //8  //9  //A  //U  //P
                                     0xD1,0xE3,0x89,0x63,0xE1,0xF5,0xC1,0x61,0x71,0xF3,0xFD,0xD5,0x85,0xFF,0X43
                                    };
//h  //L  //Y  //C  //t  //r  //b   //E //F  //I  //-  //n //d  //blank //G
unsigned int  OVOL=105;
unsigned char UVOL=75,UCRT=30;
unsigned char Sub_Pulse=1;
unsigned char Sub_Time=1;
unsigned char Sub_Relay=1;
unsigned char Sub_HMS=1;
unsigned char voltage=0;
unsigned char DecimalTOP=0;
unsigned char BLINKSEGMENT=0;
unsigned char BLINKCOUNT=0;
unsigned char BLINKFLAG=0;
unsigned char i=0;
unsigned char k=0;
unsigned char l=0;
unsigned char m=0;
unsigned char BLINKCOUNT1=0;
unsigned char BLINKCOUNT2=0;
unsigned char BLINKCOUNT3=0;
unsigned char BLINKCOUNT4=0;

unsigned char Blink_Count=1;
unsigned char Converted_Value;
unsigned int Top_Value=0;
unsigned char EEPROM_Write_Flag=0;

unsigned char EEPROM_Read_Flag=1;
unsigned int Result;

//***************************************************************************************
// Whole number broken into individual digits and converted to its LED 7 segment value.
// Called from timer interrupt.
//***************************************************************************************

void Dissect(unsigned int Value) {      // Spliting of process value in digits form
    unsigned char a,Temp;

    for(a = 8; a >= 5 ; a--) {
        Temp = Value%10;
        Value = Value/10;
        LEDBuffer_1[a-1] = DISPTABLE[Temp];

    }

}


//************************************************************************************
// Whole number broken into individual digits and converted to its LED 7 segment value.
// called outside timer interrupt.
//************************************************************************************

void Dissect_2(unsigned int Value) {            // Spliting of process value in digits form
    unsigned char a,Temp;
    for(a = 4; a >= 1 ; a--) {

        Temp = Value%10;
        Value = Value/10;
        LEDBuffer_1[a-1] = DISPTABLE[Temp];

    }

}


//===========================================================================================
// Serially transmitt display data.
//===========================================================================================
void ShiftData(unsigned char Data) {
    unsigned char i;

    STROBE = 0;
    DISPCLK = 0;
    DISPDATA = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if(Data & 0x01) DISPDATA = 1;
        else DISPDATA = 0;

        DISPCLK = 1;
        asm("nop");
        asm("nop");
        DISPCLK = 0;
        Data = Data >> 1;
    }

    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    STROBE = 0;
    DISPCLK = 0;
    DISPDATA = 0;
}



//===========================================================================================
//                          Enable strobe after data transmission
//===========================================================================================

void EnableStrobe() {
    STROBE = 1;
    asm("nop");
    asm("nop");
    STROBE = 0;
    DISPCLK = 0;
    DISPDATA = 0;
}


//===========================================================================================
//                              Display Driving Routine
//===========================================================================================

void Display() {
    switch(DgtSel) {
        case 1:

            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[4]);                  //display changed for dold
            ShiftData(0x80);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 2;
            break;

        case 2:

            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[5]);
            ShiftData(0x40);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 3;
            break;

        case 3:

            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[6]);
            ShiftData(0x20);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 4;
            break;


        case 4:
            Dec_pt=0;
            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[7]);
            ShiftData(0x10);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 5;
            break;
//************************************************************************************************
        case 5:
            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[0]);
            ShiftData(0x08);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 6;
            break;


        case 6:
            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[1]);
            ShiftData(0x04);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 7;

            break;

        case 7:

            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[2]);
            ShiftData(0x02);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 8;

            break;

        case 8:
            ShiftData(LEDBuffer_1[3]);
            ShiftData(0x01);
            EnableStrobe();
            DgtSel = 1;
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

    if(Blink_Count==1) {
        Dec_pt=1;
        //LEDBuffer_1[1]=LEDBuffer_1[1]&0X01;
        if(BLINKFLAG == 1 && DgtSel == BLINKSEGMENT) {
            BLINKCOUNT1++;
            if( BLINKCOUNT1>20)
                LEDBuffer_1[0] = DISPTABLE[26];
            BLINKCOUNT1++;
            if(BLINKCOUNT1==50) {
                BLINKCOUNT1=0;
                LEDBuffer_1[0] = DISPTABLE[j];
            }
        }
    }
    if(Blink_Count==2) {
        if(BLINKFLAG == 1 && DgtSel == BLINKSEGMENT) {
            BLINKCOUNT2++;
            if( BLINKCOUNT2>20)
                LEDBuffer_1[1] = DISPTABLE[26];
            BLINKCOUNT2++;
            if(BLINKCOUNT2==50) {
                BLINKCOUNT2=0;
                LEDBuffer_1[1] = DISPTABLE[k];
            }
        }
    }
    if(Blink_Count==3) {
        Dec_pt=1;
        if(BLINKFLAG == 1 && DgtSel == BLINKSEGMENT) {
            BLINKCOUNT3++;
            if( BLINKCOUNT3>20)
                LEDBuffer_1[2] = DISPTABLE[26];
            BLINKCOUNT3++;
            if(BLINKCOUNT3==50) {
                BLINKCOUNT3=0;
                LEDBuffer_1[2] = DISPTABLE[l];
            }
        }
    }

    if(Blink_Count==4) {
        if(BLINKFLAG == 1 && DgtSel == BLINKSEGMENT) {
            BLINKCOUNT4++;
            if( BLINKCOUNT4>20)
                LEDBuffer_1[3] = DISPTABLE[26];
            BLINKCOUNT4++;
            if(BLINKCOUNT4==50) {
                BLINKCOUNT4=0;
                LEDBuffer_1[3] = DISPTABLE[m];
            }
        }
    }


}

//********************************************************************************************
//// RUN_RESET FUNCTION
//********************************************************************************************

void PRG_RUN_RESET() {
    Bottom_Value=0;

}



//**********************************************************************************************
//// RESET KEY pressed
//**********************************************************************************************

void Key_CHK_RESET() {

    if(!RESET && !bits.KeyLock_RESET1) {        // CHECK IF SELECT IS PRESSED
        Debounce++;
        if(Debounce > 10) {
            Debounce = 0;
            bits.KeyLock_RESET1 = 1;
            PRG_RUN_RESET();
        }
    } else if(RESET && bits.KeyLock_RESET1) {
        bits.KeyLock_RESET1 = 0;
        Debounce = 0;
    }
}



//==========================================================================
//                              Timer Interrupt - 5mSec
//==========================================================================
void interrupt isr(void) {

    asm("clrwdt");

    if (TMR1IF) {
        TMR1IF = 0;
        //  TMR1H = 0x3C;
        //  TMR1L = 0xB0;100ms

        TMR1H = 0xFE;
        TMR1L = 0x0C;// timer interrupt for 1ms
        if(Top_Display>Bottom_Value) {
            Bottom_Value++;
        } else if(Top_Display==Bottom_Value) {

        }

        Display();
    }

}

//===========================================================================
//                              Main program starts here.
//===========================================================================

void main(void) {
    unsigned char value;
    unsigned char conter = 0;
    InitController();
    while(1) {

        if(PRG_EN==1) {
            if(Main_Flag==1) {
                Main_Menu(5,17,18,17);
                if(Sub_Pulse==1) {
                    SubMenu(12,14,5,20);
                } else if(Sub_Pulse==2) {
                    SubMenu(16,0,24,17);
                } else if(Sub_Pulse==3) {
                    SubMenu(24,0,5,17);
                } else {
                    Sub_Pulse=0;
                }
            }
            Main_Flag=0;

            Process_PRG_MODE();
        } else {
            Main_Flag=1;
            Process_RUN_MODE();
        }




    }
}




//**************************************************************************************************
// InitController
//**************************************************************************************************


void InitController() {

    PORTA    = 0b00000000;
    TRISA    = 0b00111000;

    TRISB =0b00001111;
    PORTB = 0b00000000;

    TRISC = 0X00;
    PORTC = 0b00000000;

    WREN=0;
    WDTCON = 0b00010111;

    INTEDG = 0; //falling edge
    INTF = 0;
    INTE = 1;
    WPUB    = 0b00000000;
    ANSEL  = 0b00000000;
    ADCON0  = 0b00000000;
    ANSELH = 0b00000000;
    ADDEN  = 0;

    PIE1=0b00000001;
    PIR1=0x01;
    INTCON = 0xC0;
    T1CON=0X11;
    TMR1IE = 1;
    PEIE   = 1;
    GIE    = 1;
    LED_SS=0;

}

//**************************************************************************************************
//RUN mode Selection
//**************************************************************************************************


void Process_RUN_MODE() {
//Display_Faults(12,18,27,26,18,11,24,26);

    if(EEPROM_Read_Flag==1) {
        READ_EPROM();
        EEPROM_Read_Flag=0;
    }
    Key_CHK_RESET();

    if(LED_SS==0) {
        Dissect(Top_Display);
        Dissect_2(Bottom_Value);
    } else if(LED_MS==0) {
        Dissect(Top_Display);
        Dissect_2(Bottom_Value);
    } else if (LED_HM==0) {
        Dissect(Top_Display);
        Dissect_2(Bottom_Value);

    }



}
```

Comment: `if my Sec paramter reaches 59s the update value should be 1min ,59s should start update again in 0` ... that is almost C code ... do the update when the counter reaches 60 though

Comment: first choose what you want to count and then figure out how to display it.  making the display count is doing it the hard way.

Comment: I know this function to be changed Dissect_2 to be changed.Since i am passing the value here. I need to change such way that character by character i should able to pass argument. where i could club and check data same time . Need suggestion in creating function.

Comment: The hard part here isn't the software, but to get an accurate enough clock.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined variables `Hour`, `Min`, `Sec` and `Msec`, but you aren't using them. Instead you just increment `Bottom_Value` on each timer tick, then convert it to decimal digits for display. The problem with this technique is that `Bottom_Value` only counts the number of milliseconds, so when you convert it to decimal you get illegal time values when the seconds or minutes go over 59.

You could extract the seconds, minutes and hours from `Bottom_Value` with a series of divisions, but this would use a lot of CPU time on a 4MHz PIC. Alternatively you could keep separate counters for them like this:-

```
Bottom_value++;
Msec ++;
if (Msec > 999)
{
  Msec = 0;
  sec ++;
  if (Sec > 59)
  {
    Sec = 0;
    Min ++;
    if (Min > 59)
    {
      Min = 0;
      Hour ++;
    }
  }
}
```

The timer tick increments `Msec`, which overflows into `Sec`, `Min` and `Hour` as each counter reaches its maximum permitted value. These variables can then be used to display the time.

BTW you should know that integers in Hitec PIC C are 16 bit, so the largest time you can store in `Bottom_Value` is 32767 ms which is only ~33 seconds. Even if you counted in 100 ms increments the largest time would only be 54 minutes. You should make `Bottom_Value` and `Top_Display` long int.

Or you could maintain separate variables for all your time values, then you could associate them in a structure like this:-

```
struct TimeVal 
{
  int Msec;
  int Sec;
  int Min;
  int Hour;
};  

struct TimeVal Bottom_Value, Top_Display;
```

and access them like this:-

```
Bottom_Value.Msec ++;
if (Bottom_value.Msec > 999)
...
```

Comment: I think here Understand wrong. Assume top display show 0210 and min flag is set. Now time is 02M 10 Sec[Set value]. now i should display process value.  i need to split top into 2 parts while taking for bottom calculation. the increment happens in sec 0-59S then 3 digit should be incremented by 1 .. next 0-59 count when it reaches 60 3 bit should increase by 2 count will conitnue till 2M 10S..  In current code time 0210 means it count upto 0210 and stops.  thats reason Dissect_2 function modified such away that first it split set value in Min.Sec  or hour. min  or  Sec.msec  .

Comment: Yes timing i have checked it creating 1mS timer interrupt .